# What are the best levels to be to help out as a sunbro?

Tags: dark-souls

I've tried helping people out for the Gargoyles boss at levels 11, 12, 13 and all the way up to 20 and it seems like it's just SUPER rare to get someone who needs help (as opposed to invading...)

At level 11 or 20, the 10% level difference is only 1-2 levels which cuts you out from helping others of VERY similar level.

What's a good level for that boss and some other common bosses that people have trouble with, like 4 kings?

Comment: Im on my ps3 playing dark souls.. it seems levels 50 - 80 were most active for me.. im currently level 111 & get a fair amount of activity but looking back i would have wanted to stay about level 75 because i dropped a group of 3 guys using darkmoon multiple times in the forest.. just a fun SL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a really good image on the Dark Souls wiki for this exact thing.

http://darksoulswiki.wikispaces.com/file/view/1323119782398.jpg/288072208/873x671/1323119782398.jpg

This will let you know what levels you should be between for there to be a great sunbro.  Using this, I was able to get around one summon every half hour from things like Smoug and Orienstein.  The level bands are pretty easy to hit, until you get to the Lords or things that can be fought at a larger band of levels (like Sif or Pinwheel).  Those areas are much more about when the player takes on the current boss.  You will get very variable level bands here, so it's very hit and miss for those areas.  But this should help you all the way up through Anor Londo.

Answer (score 5):

**Good places to help:**

Bonfire behind locked door in sewer right before gaping dragon

- Why: Easy path to the boss and most people turn human there. No one invaders in the sewer, people are likely to want help with the boss to cut down on how long it takes. They might want help with the curse frogs to explore that area.

Bottom of blight town in the sewer pipe

- Why: Easy path to the boss, most people will turn human at the bonfire and immediately summon people. Unlikely to be invaded in the sewer. Larger level range due to higher level. Very likely to have humanity and want to summon people to finish off blighttown.

Before the large stairs in Anor Londo

- Why: Path to the boss is fairly difficult and the double boss fight is made much easier with help. Slightly less good because of the more common invasions. Larger level range and almost everyone passes through this area around the same level.

The last bonfire before the crystal cave in duke's archive

- Why: Difficult if they don't have the shortcut open and confusing. Difficult path to the boss and a helper will make it more likely to pass and you can show them where the invisible bridges are.

Either bonfire in tomb of the giants

- Why: As a sunbro you are likely to have a divine weapon and can permanently kill the skeletons during the boss fight. Also your lightning spears makes killing many of the skeletons and traps much easier.

There are some of the major ones that I have found success in.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the expansion then there are two other areas to consider:

- Just before the Artorias of the Abyss boss fight. You can often get summoned there either for players fighting Artorias or those looking to kill Black Dragon Kalameet. So with one summon sign placement you can offer to help in two different fights
- Just after the Artorias of the Abyss fight in Oolacile Township. There are a lot of players there doing PvP and also looking for help with Manus

Because lots of players are exploring the new content I've found it quite easy to get summoned there.